# Django URLField and HTML5?

Tags: django, html, django-forms

Is it possible to make django's (v1.2) URLField output an HTML5 `input` tag where `type="url"`?

------------- SOLUTION -------------

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import widgets
from django.forms import fields
from models import MyObj

class URLInput(widgets.Input):
    input_type = 'url'

class MyObjForm(ModelForm):
    url = fields.URLField(widget=URLInput())

    class Meta:
        model = MyObj
```

Comment: [Django ticket #16630](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16630) is in progress to add this functionality to Django itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a custom widget for that.

```
class URLInput(forms.TextInput):

    input_type = 'url'
```

Then you can pass this widget to URLField constructor:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    url = forms.URLField(widget=URLInput())
```

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work. I got `ViewDoesNotExist ... Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'URLField'`.

I'm adding this to a model form. Do I need to do something different?

Comment: OK, I've got it. I'll update my question with the solution. Thanks.